# How to deal with security permissions when creating a file/folder from plugin

Tags: plugins, permissions, dynamics-crm-2016

I am trying to create a folder on my local computer from plugin' my code is :

```
string currentFIlePath = "C://myGeneralFile";
bool isFileInDir = Directory.Exists(currentFIlePath);
if (!isFileInDir)
{
  System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(currentFIlePath);
}
FileInfo fInfo = new FileInfo(currentFIlePath);
fInfo.IsReadOnly = false;          
return currentFIlePath;
```

At the line : `System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(currentFIlePath);` I get an error

> Request for the permission of type 'System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermission, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=' SOME NUMBER ' failed.

What can I do to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might not work for a few reasons.

1. If your plugin is registered to run within the [sandbox](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/developer/plugin-isolation-trusts-statistics) access to the *server* disk is prevented. If you are on-premise you can register your plugin outside of the sandbox which will allow you to write to the *server* disk.
2. If you are trying to write to your *local* machine disk (and not the *server* disk). This will never work, the plugin runs on the *server* and has no access to your *local* disk.